# Group counting game

Tags: probability, optimization

Suppose we have a group of $x$ people, playing a co-operative game.

The aim of the game is to count from $1$ to $x$, with each player only counting one of those integers. The game proceeds in rounds. Each round, all the players must simultaneously decide whether to call out the next number in the series. There are three possibilities of what will occur:

- Wasted round: If nobody calls out the number, then nothing happens.
- Successful round: If one and only one player calls out the number, then, in the next round, the remaining people move on to the next number.
- Failed round: If two or more people call out the number, then the count is lost and we return to $1$ to start counting again.

A player who has already called out a number becomes inactive - they no longer call out numbers. Each active player has an identical algorithm for deciding what to do in each round, with a probability ($p$) of saying the next number, and a ($1-p$) chance of saying nothing. Whenever the count is lost, all players become active again.

Let $y$ be the next number to be counted in the sequence. Find an algorithm for $p$, as a function of $x$ and $y$, in order to minimise the expected number of rounds that the game will go for.

For instance, with $x=2$ and $y=1$, it is fairly obvious that the optimal $p=0.5$. This is because both a wasted and a failed round have the same effect; so we are simply trying to maximise the probability of a successful round, which is $2p(1-p)$.

The lowest $x$ and $y$ for which calculating $p$ is challenging is $x=3$ and $y=2$. Here, a failed round is worse then a wasted round, because it requires restarting the count from $1$. Taking this into account, it works out that the optimal value for $p$ is approximately $0.357$.

Can anyone find a general formula for $p$, as a function of $x$ and $y$?